# Suppose I throw 10 balls into 5 bins probability expectancy problem

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, expected-value, balls-in-bins

Suppose I throw 10 balls into 5 labeled boxes labeled A,B,C,D,E uniformly at random. Call a pair of these boxes "special" if they are adjacent(i.e. AB, BC, CD, DE). The expected number of special boxes which are BOTH empty is?

Comment: **Clarification requested**: If $ABC$ are all empty, and $D,E$ are not empty, does this constitute exactly $3$ special boxes?

Comment: @user2661923  The problem says that a pair of special boxes is "special" if they are adjacent.  Therefore, if $A, B, C$ are all empty and $D, E$ are not, there would be two special boxes.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig You see to be assuming that if AB are the only empty boxes, that that constitutes **one** special box.  While your interpretation is reasonable, I regard it as unclear.  That is, it is not clear to me what the OP's (i.e. original poster's) actual intent is.

Answer (score 0):

What is the probability a given "special box" is empty?

Let's look at the case $AB$. For $AB$ to be empty (correct me if I am interpreting the problem wrong) means that no balls fall into box $A$ or $B$. Meaning all balls fall into $C$, $D$, or $E$.

The probability of this occurring is $\frac35^{10}$ (each of the 10 balls having a $\frac35$ chance of landing in a given box $C$, $D$, or $E$ out of $5$ boxes.

Because balls are thrown uniformly at random, none of the $4$ special boxes are more or less likely to be empty than the other. Thus, we can use linearity of expectation to find the expected number of empty boxes using the probability we found before.

Answer: $4\times\frac35^{10}$

Comment: I don't understand how you can provide an answer before the OP clarifies his intent.  See the comment that I left immediately following the posting.  The OP (i.e. original poster) has not yet responded to my request for clarification.

Comment: I am assuming my interpretation is correct based on him saying "which are BOTH empty". In the case I am not, I'll edit/delete my post